# UIAutomation how to change between apps or to the dashboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have had some strange, hard to reproduce crashes, when testing my app with an ad-hoc version on my iPhone. The crashes happened after changing from my app to the dashboard (or other app) and then changing back to the app again.

Is there a way to use UIAutomation in a way to perform these changes automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found an answer. Apple provided this line in the documentation

```
UIATarget.localTarget().deactivateAppForDuration(10);
```

This single line of code causes the application to be deactivated for 10 seconds, just as if a user had exited the application and returned to it ten seconds later.